# Error message not displaying-image upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

In my web application i have to upload an image.In that check the file is upload or not if this not upload dont show any error message

**view**

```
              public function shopped()
              {
              $config['upload_path'] = './application/assets/images/shops';
              $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';     
              $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
              $id=$this->input->post('shop_name');
              $type=$this->input->post('type');
              $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error" style="color:red">', '</div>');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('shop_name','Business Type','required');   
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('type',' shop type','required|alpha');
              if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
              {
                   $this->viewcategories();
              }
              else if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
              {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->viewcategories($error);
              }
              else
              {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $this->businesstype_model->getshop($id,$type);
                    $success_message='Successfully Added!';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message',$success_message);
                    redirect(base_url().'admin/businesstype/viewcategories');   
               }
             }
```

**viewcategory function**

```
         public function viewcategories()
       {   
          $nam=$this->input->post('name');
          $rec=$this->businesstype_model->getdata();
          $rec_array=array('rec_name'=>$rec);
          $this->load->view('admin/header',$rec_array);    
          $this->load->view('admin/addshop_view',$rec_array);
          $this->load->view('admin/footer',$rec_array);   
      }
```

I want to display the error message on addshop_view

the error message in my else if condition is not working..whats the reason for that..

plzz give a suggetion..

Comment: Where is your `viewcategorie()` function and where you want to display error message???

Comment: update my question plzz check it

Comment: use can use `$this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>')`

Comment: your viewcategory function has nor argument but in your view                   ` $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
  $this->viewcategories($error);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in addshop_view

```
// Report all PHP errors 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or this

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
```